# Java class implementation for JSON serialized using Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, microsoft-teams

I'm attempting to implement a part of the Microsoft Teams API within a Java application, and I'm looking for some advice on proper Java class structure and architecture when using the Jackson library to serialize Java objects to JSON. The goal is to send a message when certain stages are completed to a Teams channel.

I have a test class which serializes to the exact JSON I want, but based on other implementations I've seen, the code below feels like it's not structured properly and not flexible.

The JSON structure I would expect to get is below:

```
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/extensions",
  "@type": "MessageCard",
  "correlationId": "104443c6-7acc-11ea-bc55-0242ac130003",
  "summary": "test.complete",
  "themeColor": "0076D7",
  "sections": [
    {
      "activityTitle": "Test Notification"
    },
    {
      "title": "Execution Status",
      "facts": [
        {
          "name": "Build Number",
          "value": "1"
        },
        {
          "name": "Description",
          "value": "Test Pipeline Description"
        },
        {
          "name": "Execution Name",
          "value": "Test Pipeline Name"
        },
        {
          "name": "Stage Name",
          "Value": "Deploy"
        },
        {
          "name": "Status",
          "value": "complete"
        },
        {
          "name": "Summary",
          "value": "pipeline has completed successfully"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "potentialAction": [
    {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "ViewAction",
      "name": "View Execution",
      "target": [
        "https://testdomain.com"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My test Java class is below:

```java
import java.util.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;

public class JacksonSerializerTest {
  private static String ACTIVITY_TITLE = "Test Notifications";
  private static String FACTS_TITLE = "Execution Status";

  @JsonProperty("@context")
  public String context = "http://schema.org/extensions";

  @JsonProperty("@type")
  public String type = "MessageCard";

  public String correlationId;
  public String summary;
  public String themeColor;

  private transient HashMap<String, Object> metadata;

  public JacksonSerializerTest(HashMap<String, Object> metadata) {
    this.correlationId = this.createRandomUUID();
    this.summary = "test.complete";
    this.themeColor = "0076D7";

    this.metadata = metadata;
  }

  public List<HashMap> getSections() {
    List<HashMap> sections = new ArrayList<>();
    HashMap<String, Object> activityTitle = this.getSection("activityTitle", ACTIVITY_TITLE);

    sections.add(activityTitle);
    sections.add((HashMap)this.getFacts());

    return sections;
  }

  public HashMap<String, Object> getSection(String name, Object obj) {
    HashMap<String, Object> section = new HashMap<>();

    section.put(name, obj);

    return section;
  }

  private HashMap<String, Object> getFacts() {
    HashMap<String, Object> facts = new HashMap<>();
    List<HashMap> factsList = new ArrayList<>();

    factsList.add((HashMap)this.getFact("Build Number", (String)metadata.get("buildNumber")));
    factsList.add((HashMap)this.getFact("Description", (String)metadata.get("description")));
    factsList.add((HashMap)this.getFact("Execution Name", (String)metadata.get("executionName")));
    factsList.add((HashMap)this.getFact("Stage Name", (String)metadata.get("eventName")));
    factsList.add((HashMap)this.getFact("Status", (String)metadata.get("executionStatus")));
    factsList.add((HashMap)this.getFact("Summary", (String)metadata.get("executionSummary")));

    facts.put("title", FACTS_TITLE);
    facts.put("facts", factsList);

    return facts;
  }

  public HashMap<String, String> getFact(String name, String value) {
    HashMap<String, String> fact = new HashMap<>();

    fact.put("name", name);
    fact.put("value", value);

    return fact;
  }

  public List<HashMap> getPotentialAction() {
    List<HashMap> potentialAction = new ArrayList<>();
    HashMap<String, Object> action = new HashMap<>();
    ArrayList<String> targets = new ArrayList<>();

    targets.add((String)metadata.get("executionUrl"));

    action.put("@context", "http://schema.org");
    action.put("@type", "ViewAction");
    action.put("name", "View Execution");
    action.put("target", targets);

    potentialAction.add(action);

    return potentialAction;
  }

  private static String createRandomUUID() {
    return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
  }
}
```

Based on what I've been reading, it looks like I should be using nested classes for the sections and potentialAction elements, but I've been struggling with how to implement nested classes to output an array containing different hashes within those arrays.

As of right now, I'm not looking to implement the whole API, but looking to get a specific message card structure like what is shown in the JSON above. We may want to add additional features or have different message types at a later date, though.

How can this class be improved and how should this Java object be structured to be more flexible if we do need to add additional elements based on the Teams API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start of by creating separate classes for PotentialAction and Sections. This is to ensure separation of concerns. Something like :

```
class PotentialAction { 
  private List<HashMap> potentialAction;
  //all business logic to generate Potential Action goes in this class
}

class Sections {
 private List<HashMap> sections;
 //all business logic to generate Sections goes in this class
}
```

Then you create an abstract class with the minimum requirements that every api has (like metadata)

```
abstract class APICommon {
 //compulsory attributes required by all api's
 private String accessToken;
}
```

Now define API specific classes to extend that abstract class

```
class API1 extends APICommon {
 // all the api specific attributes
  public String correlationId;
  public String summary;
  public String themeColor;
  private PotentialAction potentialAction;
  private Sections sections;
}
```

Advantages:

1. By separating potential action and sections into different classes,the business logic for making different parts of the JSON are now separated which not only makes the code clean, but also reusable for different api's.
2. Going forward if you have additional requirements and the need to support new api's all you need to do is extend another class from our abstract class APICommon. This ensures that earlier implementations are untouched and makes your design extensible.

Hope this helps :)